# Memory leak when changing size of read input

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, malloc, realloc

I´m facing really weird issue with my headtail application. When I try to read from file data.txt using Powershell (command: *Get-Content data.txt | .\Headtail.exe head 10*) I always get proper and expected output. However if I change input from data.txt to fail.txt I won´t get any output from output function (called *vypis()*).

Does anyone have an idead what is going on here?

**GOOD CASE: Output from command (this output is suppose to be same using *fail.txt* as an input (meaning that content of the given input should be printed)) *Get-Content data.txt | .\Headtail.exe head 10* in PowerShell**:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.
ccccccccccccccccccccc.
dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd.
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff.
ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg.
hhhhh.
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii.
jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj.
```

**WRONG CASE: Output from command *Get-Content fail.txt | .\Headtail.exe head 10* in PowerShell**:

```
/*NOTHING */
```

**Code for my headtail function is following:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int const size = 15;
int last_changed = 0;

typedef struct {
    char **field;
    int *columns;
    int rows;
} TMatrix;

void set_size(TMatrix* matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix->rows; i++) matrix->columns[i] = size;
}

TMatrix* allocate() {
    TMatrix* matrix = malloc(sizeof(TMatrix));
    if (!matrix) return NULL;

    matrix->field = malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
    if (!matrix->field) return NULL;

    matrix->rows = size;

    matrix->columns = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    if (!matrix->field) return NULL;
    set_size(matrix);

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix->rows; i++) {
        matrix->field[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(char));
        if (!matrix->field[i]) return NULL;
    }

    return matrix;
}

void release(TMatrix* matrix) {
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix->rows; i++) free(matrix->field[i]);
    free(matrix->field);
    free(matrix->columns);
    free(matrix);
}

bool add_rows(TMatrix* matrix) {
    matrix->rows += 10;

    char** rebuf = realloc(matrix->field, matrix->rows * sizeof(char*));
    if (!rebuf) {
        free(rebuf);
        return false;
    }
    matrix->field = rebuf;

    int* rebufl = realloc(matrix->columns, matrix->rows * sizeof(int));
    if (!rebufl) {
        free(rebufl);
        return false;
    }
    matrix->columns = rebufl;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        char* rebuh = realloc(matrix->field[matrix->rows - i], size * sizeof(char));
        if (!rebuh) {
            free(rebuh);
            return false;
        }
        matrix->field[matrix->rows - i] = rebuh;
        matrix->columns[matrix->rows - i] = size;
    }

    return true;
}

bool add_column(TMatrix* matrix, int row) {
    matrix->columns[row] += 15;

    char* rebuf = realloc(matrix->field[row], matrix->columns[row] * sizeof(char));
    if (!rebuf) {
        free(rebuf);
        return false;
    }
    matrix->field[row] = rebuf;

    return true;
}

TMatrix* load(FILE* in) {
    char c;
    int actual_row = 0, actual_column = 0;

    TMatrix* matrix;
    if (!(matrix = allocate())) return NULL;

    while ((fscanf(in, "%c", &c)) != EOF) {
        matrix->field[actual_row][actual_column] = c;

        if (c != '\n') {
            actual_column += 1;
            if (((matrix->columns[actual_row]) - 1) == actual_column) {
                if (!add_column(matrix, actual_row)) return NULL;
            }
        }
        else if (c == '\n') {
            actual_column +=1;
            if (((matrix->columns[actual_row]) - 1) == actual_column) {
                if (!add_column(matrix, actual_row)) return NULL;
            }
            matrix->field[actual_row][actual_column] = '\0';
            actual_column = 0;
            actual_row += 1;
            last_changed += 1;
            if (((matrix->rows) - 1) == actual_row) {
                if (!add_rows(matrix)) return NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

bool output(FILE* out, TMatrix *matrix, double num_of_output_lines, char method[]) {
    if (!matrix) return false;
    if (num_of_output_lines <= 0) return false;
    if (matrix->rows <= 0) return false;
    if (num_of_output_lines > last_changed) return false;

    if (strcmp("head", method) == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_of_output_lines; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix->columns[i]; j++) {
                if (matrix->field[i][j] != '\0') fprintf(out, "%c", matrix->field[i][j]);
                else break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp("tail", method) == 0) {
        for (int a = (last_changed-1); a >= (last_changed - num_of_output_lines); a--) {
            for (int b = 0; b < matrix->columns[a]; b++) {
                if (matrix->field[a][b] != '\0') fprintf(out, "%c", matrix->field[a][b]);
                else break;
            }
        }
    }
    else return false;

    return true;
}

void Help() {
    fprintf(stdout, "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "* Help function - nothing important *\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (argc < 3 || argc > 4) {
        printf("!Valid count of arguments entered! \n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (strcmp("-h", argv[1]) == 0) Help();
    double num_of_output_lines = atoi(argv[argc - 1]);

    TMatrix* matrix = load(stdin);
    if (!matrix) {
        printf("!Error while loading! \n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (!output(stdout, matrix, num_of_output_lines, argv[argc - 2])) {
        printf("!Error while printing! \n");
        return -1;
    }

    release(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

**And content of data.txt (works fine, just an example input):**

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.
ccccccccccccccccccccc.
dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd.
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff.
ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg.
hhhhh.
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii.
jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj.
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk.
lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll.
mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm.
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn.
ooooooooooo.
ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp.
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq.
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr.
sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss.
ttttttttttttttttttttt.
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu.
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv.
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww.
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.
```

**And finally content of fail.txt (didn´t get any output, the difference is just in length of some rows):**

```
aaaaa.
bbbbbbb.
cccc.
ddddddd.
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff.
ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg.
hhhhh.
iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii.
jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj.
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk.
lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll.
mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm.
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn.
ooooooooooo.
ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp.
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq.
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr.
sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss.
ttttttttttttttttttttt.
uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu.
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv.
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww.
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.
```

Comment: It's not the cause of your problem, but you should not attempt to `rewind()` the standard input.  Just because *some* streams can be rewound does not mean that all can be. And the standard input typically (and in your example case) is one that cannot be.

Comment: You are right, I forget to remove it, thanks for noticing me... however as you said, it is not solution of my problem

Comment: If you want people to understand your code, make identifiers and comments in English.

Comment: I would be inclined to check whether the lengths of the lines are really the only difference between the inputs.  In particular, I would look for non-printing characters and variant line terminators.

Comment: There's a standard POSIX function `getline()` that will read a line of any length into a dynamically-allocated buffer, so you don't need to do that yourself.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Alright, I was hoping it is not needed, however it is done

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I thought so, however file "fail.txt" is only a copy of "data.txt" file with few chars deleted

Comment: @Ghost123 I compiled your program on Linux with GCC and I got expected output for both `data.txt` and `fail.txt`.

Comment: @LucaPolito, thx for good news! But more or less, I don´t know, why on Win10 it´s not working and on Linux does... :D

Comment: A possible difference ... Text files in linux/posix have a `\n` at the end. Windows text files have `\r\n` at the end. Your `if/else` [under the `fscanf`] doesn't account for that. You may want: `switch (c) { case '\n': do_newline(); break; case '\r': do_nothing(); break; default: do_ordinary(); break; }`

Comment: ... so actually *check* for that, don't assume based on the way in which you prepared `fail.txt`.  It is entirely possible that whatever editor you used emitted different line terminators for some or all of the lines than appeared in the input file.

Comment: @CraigEstey, great idea though, I was also little suspicious about line terminators, but since I always use Notepad for editing and file fail.txt is just a copy of data.txt with few chars deleted I´m afraid it´s not our culprit :D

Comment: If you implement the `\r` processing in the `switch` [which is cleaner than the `if/else if`], it's an extra `case`--like chicken soup, it couldn't hurt. IIRC, `notepad` handles only `\r\n` files but `wordpad` with handle/preserve either. To verify, you could/should dump out the file with a hex editor/dumper (e.g. `od`, `xxd` under linux) or just print it out with `%2.2X` to do it yourself. Then, you'll _know_